# Create EC2 instance in Python Boto3 with a managed policy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I want to create a lambda function using boto3 to create an EC2 instance - that part is easy enough. But I want to assign a role to that instance with an attached policy - AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore. I ended up manually creating a role "ec2_efs_role" with this permission, and tried to add that role to the EC2 instance.

I have tried for hours, but have not been able to add a role like that. I tried:

```
    iam = boto3.client('iam')

    instance_profile = iam.create_instance_profile(
        InstanceProfileName ='testforecss' 
    )

    response = iam.add_role_to_instance_profile(
        InstanceProfileName = 'testforecss',
        RoleName            = 'ec2_efs_role'
        )


    
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region)
vpc = ec2.Vpc(VPC_ID)
instances = ec2.create_instances(
     ImageId=AMI_ID,
     MinCount = 1,
     MaxCount = 1,
     InstanceType='t2.micro',
     IamInstanceProfile={
        'Name': 'testforecss'
    },
     NetworkInterfaces=[{
     'SubnetId': SUBNET_ID,
     'DeviceIndex': 0
     }],
 )
```

Error is: ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RunInstances operation: Value (testforecss) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile name

Comment: The use of `IamInstanceProfile` in `create_instances` is correct. Are you sure that `testforecss` exists and the role is correct?

Comment: I am happy that the second part seems correct at least. No the "testforecss" instance profile does not exist, that is why I want to create that instance profile in the first part of the code and attach the "ec2_efs_role" role which has the AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore permission.

Comment: The first part with `add_role_to_instance_profile` also is correct. Maybe your `ec2_efs_role` is incorrect. What is its trust policy? Is it for ec2?

Comment: The trust policy should be okay - {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I fixed the issue, apparently it works when I use "Arn" in IamInstanceProfile instead of "NAme"

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Glad it worked out. But strange, why Name does not work.